# i want to add intent in main activity

Tags: android-intent

Want to take person name to next activity and if the login is not right this will show the toast it is not working and just showing the toast.What is the that should be added in next activity and what is wrong with this code

```
       @Override
         protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



          final EditText eText1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);

         final EditText eText2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);

          final Button btn1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

          btn1.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener(){



        public void onClick(View v) {

        String str = eText1.getText().toString();

        String log= "malaika" ;

       if(str == log){

       Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),FirstButton.class);

        intent.putExtra("welcome", log);
                    }
        else {

       Toast tos =Toast.makeText(getApplication(),"wrong",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

        tos.show();
                }

          }});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all use `equals` on the place of `==` and for starting new activity

```
if(str.equals(log))
{
       Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),FirstButton.class);
       intent.putExtra("welcome", log);

       /*'welcome' is acting as a key which will carry  your
       name from this activity to the FirstButton ACTIVITY
          I suggest changing it
        */

      startActivity(intent);//for starting new activity
}
else 
{
       Toast tos =Toast.makeText(getApplication(),"wrong",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
       tos.show();
}
```

and the FirstButton activity you can get your name by

```
Intent i=getIntent();
String name=i.getStringExtra("welcome");
```

Comment: please tell me that how to show the name on next page should i use text field ?? or image view please suggest

Comment: you should use **Textview**